# WPF Smith Html Editor, how do I bind to this control in xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm using [Smith Html Editor](http://smithhtmleditor.codeplex.com/) and can't figure out how to bind my html to this control in the xaml. Do I have to do it in the code-behind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found it:

```
<smith:HtmlEditor BindingContent="{Binding MyHtmlProperty}" />
```